# Golang test with external package dependency isn't passing with Gitlab Ci, but pass in local

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have test:

```
package misc

var (
    Trace   *log.Logger
    Info    *log.Logger
    Warning *log.Logger
    Error   *log.Logger
)

func TestFTPGetFilesFromServer(t *testing.T) {
    misc.InitLogger(4) 
}

with InitLogger is located in another package

func InitSimpleLogger(level int) {
    if level == 1 {
        Trace = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[TRACE]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Info = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[INFO]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Warning = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[WARNING]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Error = log.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    } else if level == 2 {
        Trace = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[TRACE]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Info = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[INFO]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Warning = log.New(os.Stdout, "[WARNING]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Error = log.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    } else if level == 3 {
        Trace = log.New(os.Stdout, "[TRACE]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Info = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[INFO]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Warning = log.New(os.Stdout, "[WARNING]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Error = log.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    } else {
        Trace = log.New(os.Stdout, "[TRACE]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Info = log.New(os.Stdout, "[INFO]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Warning = log.New(os.Stdout, "[WARNING]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
        Error = log.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR]\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have:

```
ftph := ftp_handler.NewFTPHandler()
ftp, err = ftph.connect()
```

with NewFTPHandler()

```
func NewFTPHandler() *FTPHandler {
    return &FTPHandler{
        Addr:     os.Getenv("FTP_ADDR"),
        username: os.Getenv("FTP_USER"),
        password: os.Getenv("FTP_PASSWD"),
        key:      os.Getenv("FTP_SGEKEY"),
        iv:       os.Getenv("FTP_SGEIV"),
        Port:     os.Getenv("FTP_PORT"),
    }
}
```

and call to connect():

```
func (fh *FTPHandler) connect() (*goftp.FTP, error) {
    var err error
    var ftp *goftp.FTP
    if ftp, err = goftp.Connect(fh.Addr + ":" + fh.Port); err != nil {
        misc.Error.Println("Cannot reach the FTP server", fh.Addr, "with port", fh.Port, "\t:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = ftp.Login(fh.username, fh.password); err != nil {
        misc.Error.Println("Bad credential for the FTP server", fh.Addr, "with port", fh.Port, "\t:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return ftp, nil
}
```

When I run my test in gitlab-ci, the line:

```
misc.InitLogger(4)
```

fails at runtime

```
--- FAIL: TestFTPConnect (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5ef467]

goroutine 5 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc0000ea100)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:792 +0x387
panic(0x6af2a0, 0x9205a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
log.(*Logger).Output(0x0, 0x2, 0xc00004e0e0, 0x63, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:153 +0x47
log.(*Logger).Println(0x0, 0xc0000f9ef8, 0x6, 0x6)
    /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:188 +0x6a
gitlab.com/ColinBois/pamela/ftp_handler.(*FTPHandler).connect(0xc000050480, 0xc00002c798, 0x4766a6, 0x5c52ff3a)
    /root/go/src/gitlab.com/ColinBois/pamela/ftp_handler/ftpHandler.go:45 +0x1f3
gitlab.com/ColinBois/pamela/ftp_handler.TestFTPConnect(0xc0000ea100)
    /root/go/src/gitlab.com/ColinBois/pamela/ftp_handler/ftpHandler_test.go:20 +0x27
testing.tRunner(0xc0000ea100, 0x717140)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
created by testing.(*T).Run
```

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
test:
  image: docker:18
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - touch test.env
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker network create mygoapp_network
    - mkdir -p volume/log

  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-local.yaml up --build -d
    - docker exec mygoapp go test ./... -v
```

Comment: (*FTPHandler).connect is calling a method on a nil logger.  Show that code.

Comment: Edited ! is this the code you need ?

Comment: I think now it is ok :)

Comment: Are the tests relying on TestFTPGetFilesFromServer to initialize `misc.Error`? If so the tests are sensitive to the order that they are run in.

Comment: misc.Error is initialized by misc.InitSimpleLogger(4) - In app, it is initializes once in main.go

Comment: Maybe the FTP Service is just not accesible ? Docker container seemed to be up, but maybe it is unreachable... I will check this way

Comment: You can put it as an answer, as it is getting out of the scope of the question.  Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests do not ensure that `misc.InitSimpleLogger(4)` is executed before the tests that rely on the side effects of this function call.  Move the call to an `init()` function to ensure that it's executed before the tests.  Change

```
func TestFTPGetFilesFromServer(t *testing.T) {
    misc.InitLogger(4) 
}
```

to

```
func init() {
    misc.InitLogger(4) 
}
```